# solr join with Must clause and q and fq

Tags: solr, lucene, datastax

I have a solr query which does join on 2 different cores.
so lets say my first core has following 3 docs

> {     "id":"1",   "m_id":"lebron",    "some_info":"29"  }
>
> {    "id":"2",   "m_id":"Wade",      "matches_win":"29"  }
>
> {    "id":"3",   "m_id":"lebron",    "some_info":"1234"  }

my second core has the following docs

> {
>           "m_id": "lebron",
>           "team": "miami"
>           }
>
> {
>           "m_id": "Wade",
>           "team": "miami"
>           }

so now we made an update to doc with lebron and changed the team to "clevelend". So the new docs in core 2 looks like this.

> {
>           "m_id": "lebron",
>           "team": "clevelend"
>           }
>
> {
>           "m_id": "Wade",
>           "team": "miami"
>           }

now i am trying to join these 2 and finding the docs form core1 for team miami.

my query looks like this

> fq=+{!join from=m_id to=m_id fromIndex=core2 force=true}team:miami

I am expecting it to return doc with id=2 but what i am getting is document 1 and 2.

I am not able to figure out what is the problem. Is the query incorrect ?
or is there some issue in join.

**Couple of observations.**

1.if i remove the + from the query it works as expected. so the following query works

> fq={!join from=m_id to=m_id fromIndex=core2 force=true}team:miami

I am not sure how the Must clause affecting the query.

**2.** Also if you look the original query is not returning document 3.(however its returning document 1 which has the same m_id). Now the only difference between doc 1 and doc3 is that doc1 was created when "lebron" was part of team: miami. and doc3 was created when the team got updated to "cleveland". So the join is working fine for the new docs in core1 but not for the old docs.

3.If i use q instead of fq the query returns results as expected.

> q=+{!join from=m_id to=m_id fromIndex=core2 force=true}team:miami

and

> q={!join from=m_id to=m_id fromIndex=core2 force=true}team:miami

Both of the above works.

I am sure i am missing something how internally join works. I am trying to understand why fq has a different behavior then q with the Must(+) clause.

I am using solr 4.10

Comment: Does it work as you expect if you drop `_query_` etc. and just use the `q` parameter directly?

Comment: No. So if i give +({!join from=m_id to=m_id fromIndex=core2 force=true}team:miami) it doesnt work. If i remove the + here it works. However i am adding this in FQ. One thing i noticed is when i added this to Q instead of FQ +_query_:({!join from=m_id to=m_id fromIndex=core2 force=true}team:miami) it works. Cold it be because of cacheing ?

Comment: But why are you preprending `_query_` and using paratheses in `fq` or `q`? i.e - does `q={!join from=m_id to=m_id fromIndex=core2 force=true}team:miami` work?

Comment: lets say i drop that. even then it does not work in fq. so fq=+{!join from=m_id to=m_id fromIndex=core2 force=true}team:miami does not work. however   fq={!join from=m_id to=m_id fromIndex=core2 force=true}team:miam works. So the question is +(Must clause) is affecting the query. But i am not sure why.

Comment: Also if i put the query in q instead of fq it works with or wihout the must clause. so q={!join from=m_id to=m_id fromIndex=core2 force=true}team:miami and q= +{!join from=m_id to=m_id fromIndex=core2 force=true}team:miami both works. But i am trying to understand what is different in this case in q and fq. And why the must clause does not work when i put the same query in fq.

Comment: Why are you including `+`? The localparam should be _the first_ thing in the query. The difference might be in the default query parser for the field.

Comment: Sure i can drop that. but i still dont understand why the + works in the query but not in the filterQuery. Also we use standard query parser by default.